# Split IDs in categorical variables

Tags: stata

I have a variable with IDs:

```
clear

input ID
1
.
2
1
.
3
4
5
4
4
6
end
```

How can I create separate categorical variables with ID as a name and values of `1` and `2` (the latter if the generated variable matches the ID)?

For example, variable `_ID_1` should look as follows:

```
2
.
1
2
.
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it:

```
clear

input ID
1
.
2
1
.
3
4
5
4
4
6
end

forvalues j = 1/6 { 
    generate ID_`j' = 1 + (ID == `j') if ID != . 
} 

list
```

Comment: Note that 1 for identity, 0 for difference and missing for missing would better fit most likely uses.

Comment: This solution works here but mine is more general and can be used without knowing anything about the IDs, including whether there are gaps in between values.

Comment: @PearlySpencer: you're correct; no dissent from me, and I upvoted yours. Acceptance is in the hands of the OP and not mine to give.  In other threads you have argued for answering precisely the question asked, and not imputing or imagining one more general. My contribution otherwise was writing `separate` in the first place.

Comment: The comment was left for the OP in case s/he ever comes back. Loops are more intuitive so not surprised about the OP accepting your answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't know, genuinely. I interact a lot with non-programmers who have no idea about loops. Conversely, the readership on SO should be programmers and a programmer competent in even one language should certainly know about loops. Oddly, for all its differences the theme "there are often methods better than a loop" is common in R discussions I see, just as Stata users often have to be talked out of looping over observations.